# Singleton with constructor parameters in Kotlin

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, design-patterns, thread-safety, singleton

I have created a singleton in Kotlin as follows:

```
object MySingleton {
    var dataSource: MyDataSource? = null

    fun init(sourceUri: String, setting: String) {
        this.dataSource = MyDataSource(sourceUri).build(setting)
    }

    fun storeData(products: List<Product>) {
        dataSource?.store(products)
    }

    fun getProducts(): List<Product>? {
        return dataSource?.getProducts()
    }
}
```

I used `init` since I couldn't pass parameters to the singleton constructor but I am not sure if this is the proper way in Kotlin. Additionally are there thread safety considerations that I might be missing?

Comment: Singletons aren't a good pattern and ones with constructors are even worse. The best suggestion is not to use singletons in general. About threading well yes, there's no synchronization at all, you probably need https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-synchronized/ around each method in the worst case

Comment: @al3c: Then I guess the only way would be to have a `dataSource` as `static` somehow?

Comment: that is still global state which is as bad as singletons